# Magento - "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL" in bulk

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have 20,000 listings and had to bulk update Name (title) for all of them. We want the URL to be in accordance with new Name, but we want to keep the old URL's as well and have them 301 redirected to new URLs. If we want to do it 1 by 1, it is easy: open a new listing, erase URL key and checkmark "Create Permanent Redirect for old URL", but this option isn't available for mass updating. Is there a workaround for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is Magento CE...

The best way to do a bulk update is to use an import module. I've had to do this for the exact same reason and used this module to create Advanced Dataflow import and export jobs.

It worked flawlessly, unlike several other methods recommended elsewhere which tended to be hacks.

And also can be used to preserve your hard work by exporting the URL rewrite table and allowing you to extract your custom redirects for reimport so you don't lose them when you have to perform the occasional obligatory Core URL Rewrite reindex.

I am not affiliated with the developer, just a shop owner that didn't want to lose several years of good will from Google just because I wanted a better ecommerce engine.

[Bulk Import + Export URL REWRITES](http://www.commerceextensions.com/import-export-bulk-magento-url-rewrites-csv-xml.html)

Comment: The company seems to be some sort of scam. I ordered that module and paid for it, but cannot login to the account nor did they send me any emails with URL to download the module. Will give it a little time and see.

Comment: Check your spam traps. I know the developer's legit, been using his stuff for several years now and he's been responsive when I needed help. He does have a chat window if you need further help.

Comment: Still nothing, opened a dispute on paypal. He doesn't respond to my messages nor phone calls.

Comment: Oh, well, guess what's working for me wasn't worth recommending. Then you'll have to hunt down one of the other solutions or if you're willing to risk it, a direct import into the database. You'll need to study what are mandatory contents to meet the foreign key constraints. Create a record that's a custom permanent redirect and study the contents well. Needs some familiarity with MySQL.